# Close modal-dialog in jsf

Tags: jquery, primefaces, modal-dialog

here is my situation:
I used the dialog login example from primefaces website, and used for another situation: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf

The problem is that my dialog is modal and the code used in the example above just hide the dialog and in my situation it keeps the overlay visible. I need to trigger the 'close function' from the dialog. I tried the jquery default usage but failed miserably:

```
jQuery('#dlgComprasItens').PrimeFaces.widget.Dialog('close'); // not work
jQuery('#dlgComprasItens').dialog('close'); // not work
jQuery('#dlgComprasItens').hide(); // doesn't hide the overlay :(
```

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can you please share the code of your facelet page?

Comment: Heidarzadeh, thanks for attention, but when I saw your question I already solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's so easy, I just used the following  code:

```
                dlgComprasItens.hide();
```

Where 'dlgComprasItens' is dialog's id.